# Any Reason To Not Use ES6 Classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have never really worked too in depth in Javascript. So just starting to dig into it more, I have learned about the "new" syntax for JS: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

I understand that basically it is exactly the same as before just with a different way to construct the code.

Obviously there is always a reason to learn techniques and variations, **but what would make it worth my time to learn prototyping syntax**, when using the updated syntax is more familiar to learn?

---

*One reason I can think of is just for understanding examples from before ES6. Almost everywhere the code is written with prototyping.

Comment: Classes have no properties ( only methods), so while this is a design decision to make the whole thing more readable, prototyping could be used here to reduce duplicate primitive properties in objects ( through assigning them to their prototype)

Comment: just because you don't write code that works with the prototype syntax directly doesn't mean it wouldn't be beneficial to know what it is and how it works.

Comment: But can't you replicate having properties just the same as you would before?

Comment: @Jonasw - You don't typically put properties on the prototype because then they'd be shared by all instances of the object which is usually not what you want (as they would not be instance data).

Comment: @jfriend00 i used that for a products list. If the product has no *sold amount*, it takes the one of the prototype which is 0 ...

Comment: @Jonasw - I get that you're using it as a default value.  But, that's a bit dangerous and can confuse people using/reading your code.  Much better to just initialize the sold amount to `0` in the constructor so each instance always has its own unique value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason to avoid the `class` syntax is if you want your code to run in an environment where the `class` keyword is not supported.  And, even then, you could write with `class` and transpile your code to ES5 compatible code if you wanted.

So, there's really no reason to avoid using `class`.

---

> but what would make it worth my time to learn prototyping syntax

Even though you may code with `class`, here are some good reasons to fully understand how the prototype object works:

1. Javascript is a prototype-based language.  Even though it is now using the `class` keyword, it's a prototype-based language, not really a `class` based language.  You should know and understand what that means.
2. Older code will be written using assignments to the prototype so you will want to be able to quickly understand how that code works.
3. The `class` syntax is just manipulating the prototype under the covers so fully understanding how the `class` syntax works requires fully understanding how the prototype works.
4. There are programming structures that are sometimes very useful that the `class` syntax cannot create such as mixins where you may still need to work with the prototype.

So, I would suggest learning how objects are defined with the `prototype` object because then you will understand what the `class` syntax is actually doing.  It's not particularly hard.  Reading a few articles about how the prototype object works and then creating an object and then deriving from it using the `.prototype` object syntax is all you really need to do to get a handle on it.  Then, I'd suggest creating the exact same object definition and then deriving from it using both the `class` syntax and by assigning to the `prototype` and then you can really see the parallels.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Does this not answer the question?

Comment: I thought this was the answer I was looking for until it received a downvote. Now I am not sure if it is or not. (I assume it is still). But either way this is at least an in depth answer I was hoping to get so I could understand a bit more.

Comment: @blapaz - When downvoters leave no comment about why they downvoted and offer no opportunity for anyone to address or refute their objection, about all you can do is just ignore it as it really serves no useful purpose.

Comment: My questions getting downvoted confuses me, but not a big deal. For answers though, it makes it tough to follow if it is a good answer. However, I think your rep on here overrides that.

Comment: After reading through your edit, it makes even more sense. I appreciate this answer, exactly what I was looking to learn from this question!